# Google Cloud MySQL RestApi Multiple Outputs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following index.js file which is part of a set of files that I containerize and deploy with Google Cloud Run. This then gives me the ability to access the data in one of the tables through the RestAPI via a URL, and get my results for a specific userId by adding forward-slash then the ID I want entries for (e.g./13). I am new to all of this but my SQL query only returns one entry instead of the 5 entries there are for each ID (it's a movie recommender system that is meant to return five movies with the highest prediction). Could anyone give any info on how I can adjust it to get all output entries?

Thanks in advance!

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('REST API listening on port ', port);
});

app.get('/', async (req, res) =>  {
  res.json({status: 'API is ready to serve recommendations from ' + process.env.LOCATION});
});

app.get('/:userId', async(req, res) => {
  const userId = parseInt(req.params.userId);
  const recommendation = await getRecommendation(userId);
  res.json({status:'success', data: {recommendation: recommendation}});
});

let cachedDbPool;
function getDbPool() {
  if(!cachedDbPool) {
    cachedDbPool = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit: 1,
      user: process.env.SQL_USER,
      password: process.env.SQL_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.SQL_NAME,
      socketPath: `/cloudsql/${process.env.INST_CON_NAME}`
    });
  }
  return cachedDbPool;
}

async function getRecommendation(userId) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const sql = 'SELECT a.movieTitle, r.prediction FROM MovieInfo a INNER JOIN Recommendation r ON r.movieId = a.movieId WHERE r.userId = ? ORDER BY r.prediction desc';
    getDbPool().query(sql, [userId], (err, results) => {
      resolve(results[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without being an expert in NodeJs, I have the feeling that you always return the first line of your query with this line `resolve(results[0]);`

Try to do this instead `resolve(results);`

In addition, Cloud Run is able to handle up to 80 requests by default in the same time (you can reduce this with the `--concurrency` param). Therefore, I recommend you to set the pool connexion limit `connectionLimit: 1,` equal to the concurrency value of Cloud Run. Else, your concurrent requests will wait a free DB connexion for performing their request.